# Share screen of Microsoft Windows 10 apps using webrtc

Tags: windows, firefox, webrtc, screensharing

When a Windows 10 computer wants to share some of its screens using webrtc protocol (firefox navigator), a list of the windows that can be shared appears. In this list, only "normal" applications appears, not the one related to "apps". By example, spotify window appears, but OneNote window is not listed.

It seems (?) webrtc screen share is not compatible with UWP apps.

Knows someone a way to share the screen of an app via webrtc ?

Note: following link allows to reproduce this issue:

https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html

you do not need share anything, just push "window" and see the list of windows that appears.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Chromium (the open source version - not sure about Chrome) faces the same problem as UWP requires to use a new Win 10 API which shows it's own window selector. And then obviously that selector doesn't work on other problems. So it's a common problem on Win 10, with no known good solution as far as I can tell.